# Why most of the Websites supports only Paypal for online transaction?

Tags: credit-card

Background : There are several electronic and email based online transaction system worldwide. For example, Paypal, MoneyBooker, Alert Pay and others.

My Question : Why most of the Websites supports only Paypal for online transaction?

Comment: Because PayPal is by far the most popular.

Comment: Because PayPal is well-known, accepts most credit cards world wide, has low fees, has good fraud protection, rarely gets breached, and is trusted by consumers.

Comment: @Polynomial, +1 to your comment. :) As usual, your comments and answers helped me. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: This is not really a security question, is it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a security question, however a quick answer:

1. It's cheaper than using a credit card broker. Paypal's fees are low, meaning more take-home for websites
2. The API is easy to use and well supported.